# Using python iscpy module

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want to load in various config files, change some of the settings and write them back out again. After a search, it sounds like the [iscpy](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/iscpy) module might be useful. Trouble is I cant figure out how to use it and I cant find any examples on the web. Has anyone used it and if so can you give me some samples please?

Comment: Why cant folk have the guts to say why they downvote / request it closed?

Comment: I'll upvote to balance! Sounds like an interesting module but its poorly documented and I can't find much info either. I think its a legit question for SO.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney. To the closing police: the close is marked as 'off topic'. But in the guidelines as far as I can see it does address a specific programming problem (specifically it is how to use 'iscpy') and it is answerable and it is not going to lead to 'opinionated answers'. But most of all, some brief example of usage would be useful to many programmers.

Comment: If you haven't already try reading the documentation included in the  iscpy modules themselves. You can either look at the files directly or use `pydoc`. Then have a try at creating your own sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a program which reads an ISC-style config file, modifies the configuration, and writes a new config file:

```
import iscpy

# Read in an existing config file
with open('/tmp/named.conf') as input_config_file:
    config_string = input_config_file.read()
config_dict = iscpy.ParseISCString(config_string)

# Modify the configuration
config_dict['zone "example.com"'] = {
    'file':'"zone/example.com"',
    'type':'master'
}

# Write out the new config
config_string = iscpy.MakeISC(config_dict)
with open('/tmp/named-new.conf', 'w') as output_config_file:
    output_config_file.write(config_string)
```

Note that this transform does **not** preserve any comments or whitespace that may have been in the original.

Sample input:

```
// Boot file for LAND-5 name server

options {
        directory "/var/named";
};

controls {
        inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndc_key; };
};

key "rndc_key" {
        algorithm hmac-md5;
        secret "c3Ryb25nIGVub3VnaCBmb3IgYSBtYW4gYnV0IG1hZGUgZm9yIGEgd29tYW4K";
};

zone "." {
        type hint;
        file "root.hints";
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "zone/127.0.0";
};

zone "land-5.com" {
        type master;
        file "zone/land-5.com";
};

zone "177.6.206.in-addr.arpa" {
        type master;
        file "zone/206.6.177";
};
```

Sample output:

```
zone "177.6.206.in-addr.arpa" { type master;
file "zone/206.6.177"; };
key "rndc_key" { secret "c3Ryb25nIGVub3VnaCBmb3IgYSBtYW4gYnV0IG1hZGUgZm9yIGEgd29tYW4K";
algorithm hmac-md5; };
controls { inet 127.0.0.1 allow { localhost; } keys { rndc_key; }; };
zone "example.com" { type master;
file "zone/example.com"; };
zone "." { type hint;
file "root.hints"; };
zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" { type master;
file "zone/127.0.0"; };
zone "land-5.com" { type master;
file "zone/land-5.com"; };
options { directory "/var/named"; };
```